# Wordpress - Create Page with custom CSS and JS only

Tags: php, wordpress, reactjs

I am creating a Wordpress plugin that adds a page that embeds a React app.

On plugin activation, a post is inserted with `wp_insert_post()` function, and then the `load_app_template()` function is triggered to set the post template.
This template contains `wp_head()` in the head section and my React app.

The problem is that some other plugins are loading some JS and CSS in the head that are disturbing the React app behavior. I am trying to remove all JS and CSS given by Wordpress & other plugins and add my own.

If I remove `wp_head()` from the post template, then I cannot register styles and scripts with my plugin through `wp_register_script`.

How to remove all JS and CSS from Wordpress and plugins and add my own from my plugin ?

There could be two ways :

1. Remove `wp_head()` and manually add links to my JS and CSS in the HTML template. I can do that for Jquery and Bootstrap but I don't know how to put links of JS files from my plugin directory.
2. Keep `wp_head()`, deregister all CSS and JS and add my own afterwards with Wordpress hooks. I am not able to remove some Javascript from other plugins with this solution. I tried deregistering all following [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/17138).

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove unnecessary scripts and styles using wordpress hooks
(this might help you figure out how to do so: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233140/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-enqueued-scripts-and-styles) if your template is used on page.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove unused CSS/JS from that page. Put this code on your function.php

```
function remove_unused_css_js() {
// remove only from that page
if(get_the_ID() == 'Your Page ID'){
    wp_dequeue_style('css-id'); // remove css
    wp_dequeue_script('js-id'); // remove js
}
} 
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_unused_css_js', 100 );
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I cannot dequeue by id because I don't know the ids of the scripts and styles. It should not depend on the other plugins names so that it can be reused on other Wordpress websites.

Comment: Just view your source code with Ctrl + U command and find the css id. This would be something like this "<link rel='stylesheet' id='example-css' href='....' >". In this example your css id is "example-css".

Comment: It should work on all websites. Some other websites might have other plugins with other css ids, so this solution is not general enough.